# Vertical center icon element

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have this [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/c6jyuvc5/2/)

I want to create an 'X' button that will close the div. I can't seem to center it vertically, though. The button is actually a span with the `fa fa-times` class of [font-awesome](http://fortawesome.github.io/Font-Awesome/icon/times/).

I don't want to center anything horizontally. I want to center vertically the X in the div.

HTML

```
<div id="panel">
<span class="fa fa-times"></span>   
</div>
```

CSS

```
#panel {
    display:table;
    width:500px;
    background-color:yellow;
    height:40px;
    text-align:right;
}
span {
    display:table-cell;
    padding:4px;
    background-color:green;
    vertical-align:middle;
    margin-right:10px;
}
```

JS(doesn't matter as it's a CSS problem)

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('span').click(function () {
        $('#panel').hide();
    });
});
```

Comment: Look at the CSS vertical align: http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_pos_vertical-align.asp

Comment: dang it...busy... can't write an answer, but check this demo out: http://jsfiddle.net/y1oycoww/

Comment: To my understanding, vertical-align aligns the elements inside the element.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Adjust your CSS by using `display: table-cell` and `vertical-align: middle` on `#panel`.  Your inline `span` will then center vertically as you want.

```css
#panel {
  display: table-cell;
  width: 500px;
  background-color: yellow;
  height: 80px; /* tall height for emphasis */
  text-align: left;
  vertical-align: middle;
  padding-left: 10px; /* optional */
}
span {
  padding: 4px;
  background-color: green;
  margin-right: 10px;
  float: right;
}
```

```html
<link href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.3.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div id="panel">
  Some caption to go with the icon.
  <span class="fa fa-times"></span> 
</div>
```

Comment: This will also align everything inside your div too. http://jsfiddle.net/c6jyuvc5/3/

Comment: @GeorgeIrimiciuc If you are adding a text label to the left of the icon, simply align the text to the left and float the icon to the right.  I am assuming that the text will remain on a single line.

Comment: @jakekimds The OP seems to want everything vertically centered, and I must admit, the original post could be interpreted either way.  Your comment is correct.

Answer (score 0):

add  margin:0 auto; to your #panel. Adding this will centre the table in the page. the span will take up the full width of the #panel as it is a table cell.

you many also need to change text-align:right; to text-align:center so that the text inside your span is centered.

To keep alignment right and align button in centre, use the span as a wrapper for your button as in:

```
 <div id="panel">
  <span class="fa fa-times">
     <button>test</button>
 </span>   
</div>

 span {
     display:table-cell;
     padding:4px;
     vertical-align:middle;
      margin-right:10px;
}

button{
  background-color:green;
}
```

Comment: The thing is I don't want #panel to be centered, nor my span. I want my span to be on the right side of the div and centered only vertically.

Comment: In that case, you should use the span as the container for your button. e.g. span {
    display:table-cell;
    padding:4px;
    vertical-align:middle;
    margin-right:10px;
}

button{
 background-color:green;
}

Comment: While that will work, it adds an unnecessary button. In my example, the span is the button.